# PL/SQL Finding Difference Between Start and End Dates in Different Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I am trying to find the difference between start and end dates in different rows of a result set, using PL/SQL. Here is an example:

```
ID    TERM    START_DATE  END_DATE

423   201420    26-AUG-13   13-DEC-13

423   201430    21-JAN-14   09-MAY-14

423   201440    16-JUN-14   07-AUG-14
```

For any specific ID, I need to get the difference between the end date in the first record and the start date of the second record. Similarly, I need to get the difference between the end date in the second record and the start date of the third record,  and so forth.
Eventually I will need to perform the same operation on a variety of IDs. I am assuming I have to use a cursor and loop.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on accomplishing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably can do this in straight SQL, but your question is unclear.  Please show what you are expecting as output.  What is "first" column?  Please be **specific**.

Comment: How do you determin which start and end date you want?

Comment: More significantly, what dictates the ordering of the records? I would guess `TERM`, but this needs confirming.

Comment: If I can do it in straight SQL, I am expecting to see a DIFF_IN_DAYS column that contains the difference in days.

Comment: The records are ordered by ID, with terms for the ID in ascending order. The earliest term is the 201420 term and the latest term is the 201440 term. I would need to start with the earliest term, take that end date and calculate the number of days until the start of the next term.

Answer (score 4):

The ["lead" analytic function in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) can grab a value from the succeeding row as a value in the current row.

> Given a series of rows returned from a query and a position of the cursor, LEAD provides access to a row at a given physical offset beyond that position.

Here, this SQL grabs `start_date` from the next row and subtracts `end_date` from the current row.

```
select id, term, start_date, end_date,
       lead(start_date) over (partition by id order by term) - end_date diff_in_days
from your_table;
```

Sample output:

```
        ID TERM       START_DATE           END_DATE             DIFF_IN_DAYS
---------- ---------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------
       423 201420     26-AUG-2013 00:00:00 13-DEC-2013 00:00:00           39
       423 201430     21-JAN-2014 00:00:00 09-MAY-2014 00:00:00           36
       423 201440     14-JUN-2014 00:00:00 07-AUG-2014 00:00:00
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing... but I think you want a "PARTITION BY id" in there if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley You're right.  The question does mention "For any specific ID", so I'll add a partition by ID.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am thinking this should work, especially with the PARTITION BY.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at using the LEAD and LAG analytic functions from Oracle. By the sounds of it they should suit your needs.

See the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link. Will check out both LEAD and LAG analytic functions to see how I can make this work.

Comment: Guess I should have provided an example as per rgettman's answer! :O

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
SELECT [ID], [TERM], [START_DATE], [END_DATE],
       CASE WHEN MIN([END_DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [TERM] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)=[END_DATE] THEN NULL ELSE
       MIN([END_DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [TERM] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)-[START_DATE] END AS [DAYS_BETWEEN]
FROM [TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

`SELECT DISTINCT 
   ID, 
   TERM_CODE, 
   TERM_START_DATE, 
   TERM_END_DATE, 
   ( ( LEAD ( TERM_START_DATE, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TERM_CODE ) ) -TERM_END_DATE AS DIFF DAYS
FROM TABLE`